# Trouble with conditional statements in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a new variable by running the following code:

```
cp_phen_m$copd_dev_p2_gli = ifelse((cp_phen_m$copd_gold_p2_gli>0 & cp_phen_m$copd_gold_p1_gli==0 ), 1, 0)
```

cp_phen_m: 10234 observations

cp_phen_m$copd_gold_p2_gli: 5668 observations (numeric)

cp_phen_m$copd_gold_p1_gli: 10168 observations (numeric)

I have successfully created similar variables in chunks above with variables that contain NA values, but for some reason this function is returning the error below:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`:
! replacement has 0 rows, data has 10234
Backtrace:
 1. base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, copd_dev_p2_gli, value = `<lgl>`)
 2. base::`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, copd_dev_p2_gli, value = `<lgl>`)
Execution halted
```

I have tried changing the class of the input variables and creating a new variable using the dplyr "mutate" function.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/07/how-to-do-conditional-mutate-in-r/

```
              _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2023                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        85441                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
nickname       Eye Holes
```

Comment: make sure you don't have a typo in the variable names `copd_gold_p2_gli` and `copd_gold_p1_gli`

Comment: The variable names are correct, unfortunately.

Comment: then what does `cp_phen_m$copd_gold_p2_gli>0 & cp_phen_m$copd_gold_p1_gli==0` return for you